# Single VBA For Each Looping Through Worksheets In Workbook Multiple Times

Tags: excel, vba, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a VBA script in an excel workbook that loops through a large number of sheets (around 100) to merge data onto a single sheet. This is also data exported from PDF files. I tried to clean all non-printable characters and formatting but I'm not sure if I missed some.

It uses a single `For Each ws In Workbook` loop but when executed the script loops through the workbook a seemingly random number of times and stops at a seemingly random worksheet.  This causes a problem because sometimes when executed, the summary become 10K lines instead of 1K.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Since the data is imported from a PDF, it is not formatted in a useful way. I have other scripts that get me to this point where I can merge and use power query.  Layout of each worksheet is:

```
|------|---------------|---------|--------------|----------|
| Buy  |  Description  |  Symbol |   Price ($)  |  null    |
| null |  Lrg Co       |  VOO    |   $242.55    | 1/2/2018 |
| cont....
```

And the VBA Code (Not the prettiest but gets the job done... almost ):

```
Sub summarize()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim stcol As Integer
    Dim endcol As Integer
    Dim strow As Integer
    Dim endrow As Integer
    Dim symrng As Range
    Dim totrow As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim itm As Range
    Dim lr As Long
    
    j = 1
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        stcol = 1       
        Set symrng = ws.Cells.Find("Symbol", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)      
        strow = symrng.Row      
        endcol = symrng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).Column     
        endrow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        Set symrng = Nothing
        totrow = endrow - strow
        
        For i = 0 To totrow
            Worksheets("Summary").Range(Worksheets("Summary").Cells(j + 1, 1), Worksheets("Summary").Cells(j + 1, endcol)).Value = itm.Value
            j = j + 1
        Next i
    Next ws
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Could it be that it can't find "Symbol" and quits? Just before `Next ws`, add `Debug.Print ws.Name", run it and and see if it stops on the same ws each time.

Comment: Another possibility based on the amount of data is to change `totrow` to `Long`

Comment: Debug it with F8 and breakpoints. You need to catch that random moment you define as *a seemingly random number of times and stops at a seemingly random worksheet*, to check why it happens

Comment: @Mech I had error handling built in and it was doing the same thing.  I though it might have been the `GoTo` commands executing the loop on the same worksheet multiple times. The outcome was the same without the error handling.  I also confirmed all sheets have word symbol with another sub.

Comment: @Mech I see many scripting examples use `Long` instead of `Integer` for row counts. What is the benefit of this?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I went through the sub first with breakpoints and after looping through the lines on 20 sheets I thought it would go as planned.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @FoxFireBurnsandBurns for the idea, I ran the script with only a few sheets. I wasn't testing for the `Summary` so it kept iterating through the imported data until I'm guessing excel triggered a memory circuit breaker. Adding this line fixed it:

`If ws.Name = "Summmary" Then GoTo Nextws:`

The complete code is:

```
Sub summarize()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim stcol As Integer
    Dim endcol As Integer
    Dim strow As Integer
    Dim endrow As Integer
    Dim symrng As Range
    Dim totrow As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim itm As Range
    Dim lr As Long
    
    j = 1
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ' Exclude Summary Sheet
        If ws.Name = "Summmary" Then GoTo Nextws:

        stcol = 1       
        Set symrng = ws.Cells.Find("Symbol", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)      
        strow = symrng.Row      
        endcol = symrng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight).Column     
        endrow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        Set symrng = Nothing
        totrow = endrow - strow
        
        For i = 0 To totrow
            Worksheets("Summary").Range(Worksheets("Summary").Cells(j + 1, 1), Worksheets("Summary").Cells(j + 1, endcol)).Value = itm.Value
            j = j + 1
        Next i
Nextws:
    Next ws
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice you could resolve it on your own! :) Thumbs up!. Most of the times, when a code works but **sometimes** fails, best way is debugging slowsly with F8 and breakpoints. I know it can be boring and tedious, but indeed it works and helps a lot. Congrats